# Azure Cosmos DB - Maximum allowed point count per geometry is exceeded. Currently maximum supported number of points is 4096

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I got this error when i use the function `ST_ISVALIDDETAILED`:

[image]

This is a linestring object.

I can't find a documentation of limit or size. Is there a roadmap to increase these limits?

Is there some workaround to bypass this?

Again..

I use:

```sql
SELECT ST_ISVALIDDETAILED({ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": c.coordinate})
FROM c
WHERE (etc)
```

If the function returns false (for example because one or more points overlas) there is something (function, or procedure etc) to correct the object?

Comment: This is documented within Cosmos DB's [Service Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#sql-query-limits). As far as roadmap and future features: You may want to suggest increasing number of polygon points at the [Cosmos DB UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) area. Not really something that can be addressed here at Stack Overflow though.

Answer (score 0):

The 4096-point limit in the [Service Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#sql-query-limits) is a general points-per-polygon limit, not simply a limit applied to `ST_ISVALIDDETAILED`. As someone else said, we recommend submitting a request to support a greater number of points-per-polygon via [Cosmos DB UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) if this is something you need.

Comment: 4096 seems like a pretty harsh limit. For geo data intersections a lot of county/tract data is going to have a higher # of points than that.